# SQL: Query 2 columns; if one is valid then ignore the other

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm not sure how to approach this SQL statement so please advise, even if its just a pointer to something I can read up on

I have a table, such as the following

```
ID        OVER60      OVER80
1          N           N
2          Y           N
3          Y           Y
```

The IDs are unique, what I need to do is to create a `SELECT` statement that will return the ID, and then either 'Over 60' or 'Over 80', such as :

```
ID        AGE
2         Over 60
3         Over 80
```

What I need to avoid, is duplicates, meaning if someone is 'Over 80', then there is no need to display 'Over 60' aswel, since its pretty obvious

I've looked at `UNION` to see if that would help, and this is what I have so far :

```
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    'OVER60' as AGE
  FROM
    MY_TABLE a
  WHERE
    a.OVER_60 != 'N'
UNION
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    'OVER80' as AGE
  FROM
    MY_TABLE a
  WHERE
    a.OVER_80 != 'N'

    ;
```

What are my options? would using a `MINUS` help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a [CASE STATEMENT](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) for this.

Something ike

```
SELECT a.ID,
        CASE    
            WHEN a.OVER_80 = 'Y' THEN 'OVER80'
            WHEN a.OVER_60 = 'Y' THEN 'OVER60'
        END
FROM    MY_TABLE
WHERE   a.OVER_60 = 'Y'
```

Comment: Where for a.OVER_80 = 'Y' is redundant

Comment: Thanks Astander, I'm using the solution you suggested so accepting on that basis. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

CASE, IF, COALESCE - various approaches are possible here. A lot depends on what database server you use ;)

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this, if you want to scale well, is to re-engineer your table. Per-row functions like `case` and `coalesce` do not scale.

Don't store whether they're over 60 or 80 in the database at all. For a start, that's a variable thing changing as time goes by. Store their birthdate which is an invariant.

Then simply run:

```
select a.id, 'over 60' from my_table
    where birthdate < now() - 60 years
    and   birthdate >= now() - 80 years
union all select a.id, 'over 80' from my_table
    where birthdate < now() - 80 years;
```

With an index on birthdate, that should scream along because, unless the DBMS is brain dead, `now() - N years` will only be calculated *once*.

Comment: Thanks Pax, yes if I had the oppurtunity I would re-implement the table but unfortunately I don't have the time to do so hence the need for a CASE. I see what you mean and will hopefully learn from this ;)
 +1 anyway